# How to parse array values from Json in Jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, json-arrayagg

For the below response I need to fetch the rideId and pass it to the next request in Jmeter.Also ,the API that generates below response should be executed until the eventType is HANDSHAKE.

```
 [{"id":90856,"eventType":"HANDSHAKE","parameters":"{\"handshakeExpiration\":1669217518986,\"rideId\":3107}"}]
```

I am using the code :

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
def jsonSlurper=new JsonSlurper();
def apiDetailsArr=jsonSlurper.parse(prev.getResponseData())
def apiDetails=apiDetailsArr.size()>0?apiDetailsArr.get(0):null
def shouldRun = "1"
if(apiDetails!=null)
{
log.info("details",apiDetails.eventType+"")
if(apiDetails.eventType="HANDSHAKE"){
shouldRun="0"
}
def object=jsonSlurper.parseText(apiDetails.parameters)
log.info("xyz",object+"")

def id=object.rideId;
log.info("id",id+"")
vars.put("id", id+"")
}
else{
shouldRun="1"`enter code here`
}  


 `Condition for while controller :     `${__javaScript( "${shouldRun}" != "0",)}``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All your `log.info` function calls cause syntax errors, you can see it yourself in (surprise!) the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
2. I fail to see where you're assigning `shouldRun` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which is used in the While Controller

Suggested code change:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def apiDetailsArr = jsonSlurper.parse(prev.getResponseData())
def apiDetails = apiDetailsArr.size() > 0 ? apiDetailsArr.get(0) : null
def shouldRun = "1"
if (apiDetails != null) {
    log.info("details", apiDetails.eventType + "")
    if (apiDetails.eventType = "HANDSHAKE") {
        shouldRun = "0"
    }
    def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(apiDetails.parameters)
    log.info("xyz" + object)

    def id = object.rideId;
    log.info("id" + id)
    vars.put("id", id as String)
} else {
    shouldRun = "1"
}  

vars.put("shouldRun", shouldRun)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)